# Python if(a & !b): syntax?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What's the syntax for:

```
 if(a & !b):
```

I've been using javascript for a while and just can't seem to recall how you specify !b

Comment: That depends...are you doing something bitwise here?

Comment: What type of data are you working with? What is the expected output? (I'm not that familiar with JavaScript...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The straight translation (bitwise `and` and logical `not`) would be:

```
if a & not b:
```

As in JavaScript, this always evaluates both operands and performs a bitwise `and` operation; for example, if `b` is 0 and `a` is 2 the result will be 0 (2 & 1 == 0).

However, most probably, you meant *logical* `and` and logical `not`, as in

```
if(a && !b)
```

In Python, that would be:

```
if a and not b:
```

In this case, if `b` is 0 and `a` is 2 you'll get `True` (`2 and not 0` -> `2 and True` -> `True`).

As for `&&` in JavaScript, Python's `and` performs short-circuit evaluation, so if the left hand is `False` it won't evaluate the right-hand side, and if the left-hand-side is truthy, the right-hand-side is returned as-is (not converted to bool).

Comment: Thank you. That's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If these should represent an `AND` and a negation

```
if(a & !b): 
    ...
```

then in `Python` it could be expressed as:

```
if a and not b:
    ...
```

Comment: If the `&` in the original snippet is used as a bitwise and, then it should be `if a & not b:`. If it's not, then it should be `if(a && !b)` in JavaScript.